# Correct implementation for background task execution in web application?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have a simple servlet which merely serves some cached data back to the user.  I also have a background thread which runs at fixed intervals to refresh the cached data.  Is this a reasonable implementation?

```
@WebServlet("/CachingServlet")
public class CachingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static ScheduledExecutorService backgroundExecutor;
    private static String cachedData = "";

    public CachingServlet() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        backgroundExecutor.shutdown();
        super.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        backgroundExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        backgroundExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //implemention of fetchNewData() omitted for clarity
                cachedData = fetchNewData();  
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        super.init();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
     throws ServletException, IOException   {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(cachedData);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
     throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you needn't call `super.init();` [according to docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29), it is a NOP . but as a rule calling initializers of some superclass at the beginning of the overriding method will save you headache in the future.

`backgroundExecutor` shouldn't be static. suppose you have multiple instances of this servlet in an application. destroying ***any*** one of those servlets shuts down ***the last created*** updater. what happens to the rest?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no guarantee that the `doGet()` method will see the modified value of `cachedData`. You should synchronize the access of this field (both read and write) since the container calls the `doGet()` on separate threads than the `backgroundExecutor`'s thread. An `AtomicReference` seems the easiest solution here.

   ```
   private final AtomicReference<String> cachedDataRef = 
       new AtomicReference<String>("");

   ...


   public void run() {
       // implemention of fetchNewData() omitted for clarity
       final String newData = fetchNewData();
       cachedDataRef.set(newData);
   }

   ...

   out.println(cachedDataRef.get());
   ```
2. I'd create two local variables for the `0` and `1` magic numbers:

   ```
   int initialDelay = 0;
   int period = 1;
   ```

   Reference: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods*, *Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler:

   > Put the result of the expression, or parts of the expression, 
   >   in a temporary variable with a name that explains the purpose.

   And *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*.

Comment: Thanks @Palacsint.  Lack of synchonization was something I spotted myself after posting this and I have already added synchonization to the getting and setting of the cached data, so good spot. Also agree with your second point, but would make them static final constants and probably rename period, though not sure what's best: 'ONE_HOUR' possibly.  Anyway, thanks for taking the time to look at my code.